# Creating a new dialog using installshield

Tags: windows, installation, installshield, installscript

I followed the guide here:
http://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?t=144126
but how do I associate the installscript I wrote with the dialog box I created; everytime when I run test user interface, and click next to my created dialog box, the UI just hangs there.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the direct editor->Dialog table. You will be seeing your custom dialog's name there. In the last field of that record, you have to specify a unique number which will the the identifier for that dialog.

like the one from your example...

```
//define dialog IDs
#define RES_DIALOG_ID                                      13051  
#define RES_DIALOG_PRODUCT_UNINSTALL        13071
#define REGISTRATION_DLG_ID                    13034
#define LICENSE_DIALOG_ID                            13035
```

make sure you have the correct number referred in the dialog script.

The number referred in the function will be like this:

```
nResult = EzDefineDialog(szDialogName,"","",10790);
```